# SPutility Script Not working in Edit Form

Tags: javascript, edit-form, sputility

I have a SPutility script that I have running on my Edit Form that makes the designated form fields "Read Only". I noticed yesterday that it is not working on my real site, but is working on my test site.

The real and test sites are both in the same site collection.
Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: It seems the SPutility script is only active if I have another PreSaveAction script to go with it. The only problem is the PreSaveAction script is causing me to not be able to edit my web parts.

Comment: You must have some other JavaScript error. Have you used the F12 debugger in IE? Press f12, go to the console tab, and refresh the page. Any errors?